# How to return the whole entity referenced by a entity reference field with views

Tags: views

I have content type A with a entity reference field that references a user (let's name it `field_user_reference`). The user has `field_b` and `field_c` field. 
I've created a rest export view to return all nodes of type A with it's field which includes `field_user_reference`. My problem now is that the `field_user_reference` exported by views only contains the user's name. How do i also include the user's id, `field_b` and `field_c`?

The view returning something like this would be optimal:

```
[{"nid":"1","title":"title","field_user_reference":[{"uid":"1","name":"username","field_b":"valueb","field_c":"valuec"}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a views relationship to the user.

The relationship is usually called something like, `Entity referenced from FIELD_NAME` in your case `User referenced from field_user_reference`.

When you have added the relationship, the user's fields will then appear in the fields list.

For more information about views relationships, look here [add a relationship to a view](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/views/add-a-relationship-to-a-view).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i managed to get the user's fields value with that. But is there a way to wrap the whole entity to a key like this: `"field_user_reference":[{"uid":"1","name":"username","field_b":"valueb","field_c":"valuec"}]` rather than returning it like this: `"uid":"1","name":"username","field_b":"valueb","field_c":"valuec"`?

Comment: I’m sorry I haven’t tried that before. Maybe you can do it in a hook_views_pre_render.